# Lazy mvc.net routing

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

Am not sure if this is possible or has been asked before but I cannot find anything with regards to it.

I have a tonne of routes that will use the standard route format:

```
/{controller}/{action}/{id}/
```

90% of my site will be in this format except "id" will change a lot e.g.

```
/{controller}/{action}/{clientid}

/{controller}/{action}/{questionnaireid}
```

and so forth.  But I am lazy, as a good programmer should be, and I don't want to have to create a new route every time I have a new parameter name.

I have tried parameter binding, from another stack overflow question but I had to name the parameters in the view as the wrong thing e.g.

```
@Url.Action("users", "clients", new { id = Model.Client.ID })
```

and the BindParameter bound id to clientID so that my code reads properly.  But I don't want to have this "id = Model.Client.ID".  It needs to be "clientID = Model.Client.ID" as I like my code to be consistent throughout and no need to write comments to say what is happening and why - i'd rather the code be readable.

So is it possible to have a regular expression

```
/{controller}/{action}/{([a-z0-9]{0,255})}/
```

so that the one route will bind to {id} or {clientID}.  If I can't, I can't, and I will get over it, but I would be great.  Hope you can help.

**EDIT**
This is not about the value of the parameter, but the name of the parameter on the action method.  I basically don't want to have 50+ routes that are only different by the name of the parameter on the action.

Comment: AFAIK, from looking at the source code, a `RouteValueDictionary` is created where (in your first example above) the keys are `"controller"`, `"action"` and `"id"`, with the values mapped to these keys, so using the regular expression would just create the key `"([a-z0-9]{0,255})"` (which does not exist). So I think you are going to have to create multiple routes or change all the parameters in your methods to `id`. And are you accusing me of being lazy or not a good programmer? :)

Comment: What's wrong with simply using id for all your routes?  I mean, if your Controller is Questionaire, and your action is Edit, id would obviously be questionaireid would it not?  I don't see the need to change the name in all your routes, that just seems like a waste of effort.

Comment: Erik : Fine for Edit. But I want all the users of a client -  /Client/Users/{id} maps to public ActionResult Users(Guid id) { } but id (to me) doesn't make it readable - okay you can add comments etc. but am lazy.

/Client/Users/{clientID} makes my action readable ActionResult Users(Guid clientID) { } so that I can call UserService.FetchAllByClientID(clientID) and thus all is happy (in my world). 

Make sense?

Stephen - yeah I knew about that with the regular expression.  And yeah it looks like I will have to have the 50+ routes :(

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if i get correctly what you need, but you may have some reglar expressions in the `constraints` property of the MapRoute:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "clientRoute",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{clientid}",
    defaults: ...,
    constraints: new {clientid=@"[a-z0-9]"}
);
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "plainIdRoute",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: ...,
    constraints: new {id=@"{0,255}"}
);
```

I have not checked the validity of the regular expressions.

You also need to keep in mind that if an id matches both rules, then it will get the first one, so you should make sure you do not have overlaps.

Comment: That is constraining what the value of id is, not what "id" is called.

I basically don't want to have 50 routes that are only different by the name of the parameter on the action.